# Foreign key tied to autoincrement primary key won't translate negative numbers to the actual values

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-ce-4

I'm working on a small application that parses an html file and adds text to two database tables that are related. I'm using MSVC# 11 and SQL CE.

I understand why autoincrement identity values are negative in the dataset designer, and when I look at both tables, they contain the same negative numbers, so I can see that the relation is correct.

However, the database engine never seems to convert the negative number of the foreign key to the primary key after the database engine assigns a positive primary key.

The "refresh data table" setting is also greyed out in the dataset designer. So I'm not sure how to get the correct identity values.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I figured I'd do a quick update.  I dropped SQL Server CE and I'm using SQL Server Express, everything works fine now.